# Why should we cast to the same type?

Tags: java, arrays, casting

can anyone explain why am i getting incompatible type error and should 
cast to `Object[]` if `ref[0]` is already object array(`class [Ljava.lang.Object;`)

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Object[] ref = new Object[1];
        Object[] x = new Object[]{1};
        while (true) {
            ref[0] = new Object[]{ref};
            System.out.println(ref[0].getClass()); //class [Ljava.lang.Object;
            ref = ref[0]; // incompatible type error
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `ref` is an array and `ref[]` is just one element from an array! for that you get `incompatible type error`

Comment: This while loop: does it ever terminate?

Comment: @laune i'm just learning how memory works.

Answer (score 3):

At compile stage, `ref[0]`'s data type is `Object`, `ref`'s data type is `Object[]`.

`Object` and `Object[]` are not the same type.

Comment: when i tell "ref[0] = new Object[]{ref};" is it like ref[0] = (Object unnamed = new Object[]{ref})

Comment: Yes. But the compiler does not know `ref[0]`'s real data type is `Object[]`. To make it compile, you have to cast it explictly `ref = (Object[]) ref[0];`